# Transposing and identifying the cell with a flag

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

I have a table with three columns. The value column is always `NULL`. I know how to transpose the rows into columns but I also want to identify the cell with an 'X'.

Table

```
EditorTypeSymbolicName ClaimFieldSymbolicName Value
01                     AA                     NULL
01                     BB                     NULL
01                     CC                     NULL
02                     BB                     NULL
02                     CC                     NULL
03                     AA                     NULL
```

Here is my code

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(ClaimFieldSymbolicName)
            FROM #TempEditElements
            ORDER BY 1
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

SET @sql = 'SELECT EditorTypeSymbolicName, ' + @cols + '
              FROM
            (
              select EditorTypeSymbolicName, ClaimFieldSymbolicName, Value 
              from #TempEditElements
            ) s
            PIVOT
            (
              MAX(Value) FOR ClaimFieldSymbolicName IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) p
            order by EditorTypeSymbolicName'

EXECUTE(@sql)
```

My code transposes it but I don't know how to flag them with the 'X'. I want the output to be like:

```
EditorTypeSymbolicName  AA   BB   CC
01                      X    X    X
02                      NULL X    X
03                      X    NULL NULL
```

Current output looks like this

```
EditorTypeSymbolicName  AA   BB   CC
01                      NULL NULL NULL
02                      NULL NULL NULL
03                      NULL NULL NULL
```

Comment: What do you mean by _identify_? Do you want to restrict the result to the rows that contain 'X' in _Value_ column?

Comment: What does the current output look like? Could you add that to your question please?

Comment: @TT - Added current output.

Comment: @Gerardo Lima - I want to identify wherever an EditorTypeSymbolicName has a ClaimFieldSymbolicName by an X when that ClaimFieldSymbolicName is transposed to a column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be one way to do it. In the dynamic query,

- A "matrix" is created for `EditorTypeSymbolicName X ClaimFieldSymbolicName` (the `CROSS JOIN` part)
- This is then linked to the original table to look up if a row exists for each combination (the `LEFT JOIN` part)
- If a row exists, the `Value` is substituted with the `X` you need (the `Value=CASE ...` part)

---

```sql
CREATE TABLE #TempEditElements(EditorTypeSymbolicName VARCHAR(128),ClaimFieldSymbolicName VARCHAR(128),Value VARCHAR(128));
INSERT INTO #TempEditElements(EditorTypeSymbolicName,ClaimFieldSymbolicName,Value)
VALUES ('01','AA',NULL),('01','BB',NULL),('01','CC',NULL),('02','BB',NULL),('02','CC',NULL),('03','AA',NULL);

DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(ClaimFieldSymbolicName)
            FROM #TempEditElements
            ORDER BY 1
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

SET @sql = 'SELECT EditorTypeSymbolicName, ' + @cols + '
              FROM
            (
                SELECT 
                    ets.EditorTypeSymbolicName,
                    cfs.ClaimFieldSymbolicName,
                    Value=CASE WHEN tee.EditorTypeSymbolicName IS NULL AND tee.ClaimFieldSymbolicName IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE ''X'' END
                FROM
                    (SELECT DISTINCT EditorTypeSymbolicName FROM #TempEditElements) AS ets
                    CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ClaimFieldSymbolicName FROM #TempEditElements) AS cfs
                    LEFT JOIN #TempEditElements AS tee ON 
                        tee.EditorTypeSymbolicName=ets.EditorTypeSymbolicName AND 
                        tee.ClaimFieldSymbolicName=cfs.ClaimFieldSymbolicName
            ) s
            PIVOT
            (
              MAX(Value) FOR ClaimFieldSymbolicName IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) p
            order by EditorTypeSymbolicName'

EXECUTE (@sql);

DROP TABLE #TempEditElements;
```

Result is:

```
╔════════════════════════╦══════╦══════╦══════╗
║ EditorTypeSymbolicName ║  AA  ║  BB  ║  CC  ║
╠════════════════════════╬══════╬══════╬══════╣
║                     01 ║ X    ║ X    ║ X    ║
║                     02 ║ NULL ║ X    ║ X    ║
║                     03 ║ X    ║ NULL ║ NULL ║
╚════════════════════════╩══════╩══════╩══════╝
```

Comment: Thank you for soln:

Comment: **(1)** there should be no logic for **value** it is simply **'X'** **(2)** The way PIVOT works, there is no reason to generate all the combinations of **EditorTypeSymbolicName** and **ClaimFieldSymbolicName**. Once you have a value in **EditorTypeSymbolicName** a row will be created in the pivot table. For the columns created based on **ClaimFieldSymbolicName** you already took care at the previous part. Any square in the pivot table will hold 'X' if there is at least one row in the original table with its **EditorTypeSymbolicName** and **ClaimFieldSymbolicName** value or NULL otherwise.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz You got a point. For questions like these I'm not really shaving the solution to be the best, I just cook something up that works.

Comment: @TT.P.s. how did you generate the result table?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Execute the script, then in SSMS right-click the top-left header of the result table and choose "copy with headers". Go to https://senseful.github.io/web-tools/text-table/ and paste the table in the input field. Select "Unicode Art" in style, click "Generate Table". Select all in the Output. Then paste in the answer field & format as code block. See my profile for more interesting links.

Comment: @TT. Thanks, I tried it few hours ago and got an error message (something about line separator) no matter what I did and now it's working..

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Cool :p

Answer (score 1):

## static solution

```
select      *

from        (select 'X' as x,EditorTypeSymbolicName,ClaimFieldSymbolicName from t) t 
                pivot (max(x) for ClaimFieldSymbolicName in ([AA],[BB],[CC]))   t

order by    EditorTypeSymbolicName
;
```

## dynamic solution

```
declare @columns    nvarchar(max)   = ''
       ,@stmt       nvarchar(max)
;

----------

select      @columns += case @columns when '' then '' else ',' end + QUOTENAME (ClaimFieldSymbolicName,'[')

from        t

group by    ClaimFieldSymbolicName

order by    ClaimFieldSymbolicName
;

----------

set @stmt =

    '
    select      *

    from        (select ''X'' as x,EditorTypeSymbolicName,ClaimFieldSymbolicName from t) t 
                    pivot (max(x) for ClaimFieldSymbolicName in ('+ @columns + '))   t

    order by    EditorTypeSymbolicName
    '
;

----------

exec (@stmt)
```

## semi static solution

```
select      (select top 0 EditorTypeSymbolicName from t) as EditorTypeSymbolicName,t.*

from        (select distinct ClaimFieldSymbolicName,dense_rank () over (order by ClaimFieldSymbolicName) as dr from t) t 
                pivot (max(ClaimFieldSymbolicName) for dr in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10])) t


union all

select      *

from        (select 'X' as x,EditorTypeSymbolicName,dense_rank () over (order by ClaimFieldSymbolicName) as dr from t) t 
                pivot (max(x) for dr in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10])) t

order by    1
;
```

---

```
╔════════════════════════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╗
║ EditorTypeSymbolicName ║  1   ║  2   ║  3   ║  4   ║  5   ║  6   ║  7   ║  8   ║  9   ║  10  ║
╠════════════════════════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╣
║ NULL                   ║ AA   ║ BB   ║ CC   ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ NULL ║
║ 01                     ║ X    ║ X    ║ X    ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ NULL ║
║ 02                     ║ NULL ║ X    ║ X    ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ NULL ║
║ 03                     ║ X    ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ NULL ║
╚════════════════════════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╝
```

Comment: I need it to be dynamic because the number of transposed columns is many

Comment: @user176047, that means you only need to concatenate the column identifiers, e.g., **AA,BB,CC** and push it into this query. I trust you to do it

Comment: Yeah, i tried using the 'at'cols in "t.ClaimFieldSymbolicName in ('at'cols))" but i get a syntax error. i declare the 'at'cols and stuff it with the column names like in my above query in the OP.

Comment: @user176047, please check the dynamic solution (answer edited)